# MySQL incomplete table data after export and import

Tags: mysql, import, export

We are trying to migrate a very heavy table (about 23GB) from a hosted server to a virtual private cloud with a MySQL instance running in it.

For all the other (smaller) tables that we have, the following procedure works perfectly:

Dump and compress the data on the origin server:

```
mysqldump -u user -p db table | gzip > table.gz
```

Send the data to the server that is in the cloud using rsync:

```
rsync -avz -e ssh root@gold.net:/path/table.gz .
```

import the data into MySQL using:

```
gzip -dc < table.gz | mysql -u user -h {LOCAL IP OF DB INSTANCE} -p db
```

When using this procedure for the large table (again, about 23GB), rows are missing from the target database (this has been tested more than once). Many rows do load successfully, but it is evident that a large amount of the data is missing.

The MD5 of the .gz file is the same both on the source server and the target one.

What else could possibly be going wrong here?

Comment: Did you check your exported table data in your source server with in different db or table name? Maybe your destination server's config arises the problem?

Comment: I am a little confused - what do you mean exactly by checking the source server with in different db or table name?

Comment: Well, when you export your big table, impoort it again in your same server, if your new table dont have missing rows, you can say that your new server has problems with importing.

Comment: i am unfortunately unable to do that due to disk space limitation on my original server. that is one of the reasons we are migrating...